# Automate the Boring Stuff with Python - Comma Code

Tags: python

So I've come up with a working solution that doesn't use an oxford comma through a bit of a bodge, is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
def stringy(spam):
    output = ""
    for thing in spam[:-1]: 
        output = output + thing + ", "
    output = output[:-2] + " and " + spam[-1] #removes the last 2 chars 
    return output

spam = ['cats','cats','cats','cats', 'apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

print(stringy(spam))`
```

Comment: `", ".join(spam[:-1]) + " and " + spam[-1]`

Comment: what to do if there are less than 2 elements in `spam`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def list1(name):
    name = name.insert(len(name)-1, 'and')
    for i in range(len(spam)-2):

        print(spam[i] ,end=', ' )
    print(spam[-2], end=' ')    
    print(spam[-1],end='')



spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats' , 'hello']
list1(spam)
```

Comment: Good solution, although the first `end` makes the comma go after the space and not before.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```
def stringy(spam):
    if len(spam) < 2:
        return ' and '.join(spam)
    else:
        return ', '.join(spam[:-1]) + ' and '+spam[-1]

spams = [['cats','cats','cats','cats', 'apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats'],['tofu', 'cats'],[]]

for spam in spams:
    print(stringy(spam))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what @Azat Ibrakov had in a one-liner, I'd just warn againts `+` for string operations in python.

```
def commanize(spam: list):
    if len(spam) >= 2:
        comma_str = ', '.join(spam[:-1])
        return ' and '.join([comma_str, spam[-1]])
    else:
        return spam[0]

assert commanize(['a', 'b', 'c'])  == 'a, b and c'
assert commanize(['a', 'b'])  == 'a and b'
assert commanize(['a'])  == 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer and first post!

```
def returnString(list):
    length = len(list)
    i = 0
    outputstring = list[i]
    i += 1
    while i < length - 1:
        outputstring = outputstring + ', '+ str(list[i])
        i = i + 1
outputstring = outputstring + ' and ' + list[i]
print(outputstring)

list = ['Ants', 'Spiders', 'Rabbits', 'Leopards', 'Lions', 'Tigers', 'Elephants']
returnString(list)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check that code in your answer is possible to execute. You will probably want to fix the indentation. Also, please explain why you think that your answer is better than the existing ones. Note that your solution fails if the list contains less than two items.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
", ".join(spam[:-1]) + " and " + spam[-1] if len(spam)>1 else spam[-1] if len(spam)>=1 else ""
```

[image]

Comment: will fail on empty `spam`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov what mistake in this makes awful??